# Regular expression remove the special character from a file name for Windows

Tags: javascript, regex

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx,
We know Windows reserve some characters:

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

I have a file name which contains come of those special characters,
I want to replace those with "",
something like this (string.replace(/\<>/g, '')
Thanks

Comment: This is a challenging request as Windows has odd file name rules. See this SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754307/regex-to-replace-characters-that-windows-doesnt-accept-in-a-filename

Comment: thanks, I didn't find it when I google it. Sorry for ask dumplicate question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put all those characters inside a character set:

```
string.replace( /[<>:"\/\\|?*]+/g, '' );
```

Comment: I would also add the octothorpe/pound/number symbol # to the regular expression, as this character makes the file unlinkable by some encoders